# Differential problem in Gausses law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

From the Gauss law we know, $\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \rho / \epsilon_0 $.

We have given that, $\vec{E}= kr^3  \hat {r}$

[image]

Now I have problem to get the identified part.  Can you please elaborate that?

Comment: $E_{r} = kr^{3}$.

Comment: I wanted to understand the the previous step?

Comment: That's the formula for divergence spherical coordinates (when the force is radial). Gauss's Law applies to the usual electromagnetic fields (given by inverse square laws), not to an arbitrary $\vec E$.

Answer (score 1):

See, e.g., [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) for the formula for the various differential operators in cylindrical and spherical coordinates.